# Converting Double Integrals to Polar Form - Ron Larson Calculus 8th Edition Chapter 14 Section 3 Problem #15

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I'm new to this forum and trying to self-study Calc 3 from an online textbook. I'm working through the practice-sets of this book, but the solution appears to be different from what I had expected.

[This](https://www.calcchat.com/book/Calculus-8e/14/3/15/) is a link to the problem. I had converted the bounds of the two integrals successfully, but when met with the equation within, I had assumed that it would be $y = r*sin(\theta)$, like in standard 2D rectangular to polar conversion methods. Instead, the correct solution appears to be $r^2*sin(\theta)$, and I'm not sure where this additional multiplicand of r comes from, or if I'm approaching this correctly at all. I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Comment: You have to convert $dxdy$ too like you would in a single variable calculus change. In this case, $dxdy=rdrd\theta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When some change of variables is done you also have to multiply by the jacobian of the change of variables which, in the case of polar coordinates, is the radius $r$

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant